# jquery and the use of $.getScript()

Tags: jquery

here is the code

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(            
            function(evt) {                        
                if( !window.sayHi ) {
                    evt.target.disabled = "disabled";
                    $.getScript("hi.js", function() {
                        sayHi($("input[type=text").val());
                        evt.target.disabled = "";
                    });
                }
                else{
                    sayHi( $("input[type=text").val() );
                }
            });
});
```

what will happen if i click on button repeatedly then $.getScript() will download hi.js file repeatedly or only first time?

$.getScript() check the js file exist in client machine or not....if not then it download only? please discuss. thanks

i got the detail about getScript() function. here i am giving the code where i stuck for few lines.

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function(url, options) {

// allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
options = $.extend(options || {}, {
dataType: "script",
cache: true,
url: url
});

// Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
// Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
return jQuery.ajax(options);
};

// Usage
$.cachedScript("ajax/test.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
console.log( textStatus );
});
```

1) cachedScript() function need two argument but only one is sending at the time of calling....why?

2) from where done() function come here?

please explain the above two points

Comment: all explained her http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Don't be lazy... read the docs of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery appends the current Unix epoch as a GET param so it will be downloaded for each `click` event (provided they don't occur in the same millisecond) :P.

> Be default, `$.getScript()` sets the cache setting to false. This
>   appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure
>   that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested. You
>   can override this feature by setting the cache property globally using
>   `$.ajaxSetup()`.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests).

It'd be good form to set a flag and test for it or look for a variable that is defined in the new script. Then write a condition based on that.

Comment: i update my question with more doubts. if possible then please have a look & reply. thanks